# Is it possible to plot/get burndown charts in a sinusoidal wave form rather than squar wave form?

Tags: jira, project-management, jira-plugin

As a JIRA newbee and explorer, I seek your help in determining whether it's possible to draw curvy (sinusoidal waveform) graphs.

Currently, the burndown charts which I am getting are of square-wave form.

If sine-wave is possible then kindly let me know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any out-of-the-box solution for that. If you don't mind doing some programming (shouldn't take more that a few hours for someone with basic programming skills), you can use one of [Jira's remote API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Remote+API+Reference) together with [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/) to build whatever Chart you want.

Than, to display the graph on Jira you can use the [custom content plugin fro Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.tngtech.jira.plugins.customcontent.jira-gadget-custom-content).

Comment: I dont have so much time to do all such stuff as such I am jam packed wioth development.... this is just for the sake of tracking I was exploring...if theres no ready to implement method available then I believe I should compromise with whatever is available.. Thanks for the help @Kuf